# Make AJAX GET query to a url and insert content returned to a div

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Given the url -

How can I make an AJAX GET query (on page load) to the url above and insert the content returned in to an empty div tag on an HTML page?

```
<div id="ajax-result"></div>
```

I have tried the .load method with jQuery but its not working

```
    var url 
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#ajax-result').load('url');
});
```

any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried? Read something? Did you write few lines of code? Sharing your code is preferred.

Comment: This is a basic flow. You can find plenty of examples of this online. We can help, if you share, what you tried.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: I added code that I tried using jQuery but its not working, looks like it works when I use a url from my localhost but can't load remote

Answer (score 1):

Due to [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), you can't make ajax calls to a domain that is different to that of your code.

A possible solution is to proxy the request through a server side script on your domain. So you'd make an ajax call to your own domain, which would invoke a script to do the request to the other domain via server to server communication. The third party would give the response to your server side script, which in turn can pass the response on through the ajax response.

Comment: so in this case how do we proceed with that?

Comment: @Patrick Ndille: [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) will do that.

Comment: @PatrickNdille it depends what server side scripting language you want to use. But the principle is the same for all: to send a server to server request to the third party and return it as the ajax response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this javascript library cross-domain-ajax:

```
https://github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/blob/master/cross-domain-ajax/jquery.xdomainajax.js
```

or as workaround ajax to own domain and pull the resources server-side